# Is Drop down possible under renderdatatable

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I have a simple application below. is it possible to create to dropdown for each column with column values

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
DT::dataTableOutput('a')
output$a <- DT::renderDataTable(
    iris)
```
````